# How to create IQueryable results using Entity Framework complex types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following Service Operation where DataDTO is a ***complex type*** (added via Entity Framework Model Browser):

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<DataDTO> GetInformation(string id)
{
 var resultList= (from data in context.Data
                  where data.ID ==id
                  select new
                  {
                   DataID = data.ID,
                   Name = data.Name,
                   Group = data.Group
                  })
               .ToList()
               .Select(item =>
                  new DataDTO
                  {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Name= item.Name,
                    Group = item.Group
                  });
 return resultList.AsQueryable();
}
```

When I access it with a client, I get an exception:

> Query options $orderby, $inlinecount, $skip and $top cannot be applied
>   to the requested resource.

So adding AsQueryable does not solve the issue.

How should I modify the query to return IQueryable considering the usage of the complex type?

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:Add the [SingleResult] attribute on the service operation method to let WCF DS know that the IQueryable is only gonna return a single value

Solution 2:WCF OData service methods do not support query options.Try disable paging for your data source by setting the DataSource.paginate option to false

Comment: As I return a _list_ of entities, using `SingleResult` is not good for me. Also, paging is the essence of Data Services, I intend to keep using it, so your suggestions will not help me.